# Can Spring XD be used as a platform for comprehensive Spring batch workflows?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

Spring XD provides platform for launching for the batch jobs. Does that cover comprehensive workflows for all batch job use-cases? Or it is meant to be used within the context of Spring XD use-cases.

For example someone who wants to use just spring-batch not necessarily all the features of data ingestion/real-time analytics, will they still be benefited by setting up the Spring XD DIRT just for executing batch workflows? In that case, are there any limitations not being able to use all batch workflows supported by spring-batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes it can be used as a comprehensive batch platform.  Spring XD provides a number of compelling features currently with more coming in the future.  Features Spring XD provide for batch solutions:

- **Job orchestration** - Spring Batch explicitly avoids the problem of job orchestration so that the developer can use whatever tool they want.  Spring XD brings orchestration in a distributed environment via scheduling of jobs, executing ad hoc jobs, and executing jobs on the result of some form of logic (polling a directory for a file for example).
- **Abstraction of Spring Batch and Spring Integration** - Spring Batch and Spring Integration are commonly used in solutions to address more complex scenarios.  For example, if you need to FTP a file to a server, then kick off a batch job once it's there, you'd use Spring Integration for the FTP piece and to kick off the job with Spring Batch handling the processing of the job.  Spring XD provides an elegent abstraction of those components to allow for easy assembly of these into more robust solutions.
- **Simplification of remote partitioning** - Spring XD provides facilities to simplify the wiring of the communication aspects of remote partitioning within Spring Batch.
- **Interaction of jobs via UI, shell, or REST** - Spring XD exposes a number of metrics and functionality to be consumable via their web based UI, the interactive shell, or REST based end points.

The main limit as of Spring XD 1.0 for batch processing is the inability to execute nested jobs (using a JobStep).  I believe this will be part of Spring XD 1.1 (https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-1972).

Looking forward, other features that I would expect in future versions of Spring XD are around high availability for jobs.  Currently if a job is deployed on a node and the node goes down, it will be redeployed automatically.  In future releases, the ability to restart the job automatically upon redeployment would be possible.